# How can I install Pootle using Git?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, pootle

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and am trying to install version 2.7 of [Pootle](https://github.com/translate/pootle), which I've been told I should do with Git rather than pip, which I think is because this version is not stable and so doesn't have a pip package/is not yet set up for use with pip. But not being familiar with Python (and am not really much of a programmer at all) I am having trouble with intialising the database with `manage.py`.

So far I have checked out the master branch to `/srv/www/pootle/project` and upgraded Django in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django` to version 1.7.7 using `pip`. (See [Pootle 2.7 requirements](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/pootle/en/latest/releases/2.7.0.html).)

I had previously successfully installed Pootle version 2.5 using pip and the `pootle setup` to initialise the database, but because Pootle 2.7 has [removed the `pootle setup` command](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/pootle/en/latest/releases/2.7.0.html#minor-features), I've been trying to initialise the database with `./manage.py initdb`. That results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 20, in <module>
    cmd_log(*sys.argv)
  File "/srv/www/pootle/project/pootle/core/log.py", line 61, in cmd_log
    fn = settings.LOGGING.get('handlers').get('log_action').get('filename')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 46, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 42, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 115, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

I suppose this is because the Django settings are being used, and not my settings at `/srv/www/pootle/pootle.conf` which has my secret key and other config.

I've tried using the `--settings=pootle` option with `manage.py` and `django-admin.py`, with a symlink in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/` and `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/` named `pootle.settings` leading to my `pootle.conf`, but still get `The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the difference is that when you install Pootle via pip, you have available the `pootle` command, which has a [convenience runner](https://github.com/translate/pootle/blob/a9049c9c3c664d011a3d0270b2e316b8840e271a/pootle/runner.py) that sets things up for you, including the path to the custom settings file. When you use a git clone, the convenience magic is unavailable.

Long story short, you need to set the `POOTLE_SETTINGS` environment variable to the path of your custom settings file.

```bash
$ POOTLE_SETTINGS=/srv/www/pootle/pootle.conf python manage.py initdb
```

Alternatively, and since you are trying out a git clone, you can rename your settings file to something like *90-custom-settings-local.conf* (*90-* is important, as well as the *.conf* extension; *-local* is handy as it's in [Pootle's *.gitignore*](https://github.com/translate/pootle/blob/a9049c9c3c664d011a3d0270b2e316b8840e271a/.gitignore#L29)) and drop it into *pootle/settings/*, and it'll pick it up. No need to set the `POOTLE_SETTINGS` env var with this method.

Comment: Thanks! I now have `File "/srv/www/pootle/project/pootle/checks.py", line 101, in check_redis <br>
conn_settings = queue.connection.connection_pool.connection_kwargs <br>
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'queue' referenced before assignment` - perhaps I need to configure a Redis queue? I'll look into this soon. Btw, I found that I needed to use `./manage.py` to get it to execute, but can't edit an answer without changing 6 characters.

Comment: Re. the error you hit, yes you do need Redis, but here the underlying issue is you haven't installed all the required dependencies, more precisely `django-rq`. Please install the deps using `pip install -r requirements/base.txt`